# Changing table schema in sql 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a sql 2005 database and I have a table named dbo.AgencyProfile
However, I want to remove the dbo prefix. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the prefix/schema but you can change it by recreating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [whatever].[AgencyProfile](
        [AgencyId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT
        [AgencyName] [nvarchar](256),
        [Field 2] [nvarchar](256),
        [Field 3] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL 
etc....
```

Comment: Its client policy they way the systems are set up here. Not much I can do to change those policies.

Comment: @user279521: policy to *not* use dbo?

Comment: @Ricardo: No need to recreate the table... see my answer please

Comment: @gbn You are right about that! I used the CREATE command assuming this will help other people that want/need to use a different schema when creating tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to?  SQL keeps all objects in the `dbo` schema my default.  You don't need to use the schema in your SQL statements - `SELECT * FROM AgencyProfile` will do fine because SQL will search the `dbo` schema for `AgencyProfile`.

You can put objects into your own schemas, but then you do need to qualify them with your schema name.

Comment: When I do a select, I get an
Invalid object name 'dbo.AgencyProfile'.

Answer (score 1):

The schema is an integral part of the object: you can only remove it from code that refers to the object

There is a performance hit at compile time because it has to resolve what schema the object is in.

`SELECT * FROM foobar` is not the same `SELECT * FROM dbo.foobar` and will require a check to see what schema `foobar` is in. That is, it will look for `[domain\user].foobar` before going to `dbo.foobar`.

From ["Execution Plan Caching and Reuse"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx):

> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> The algorithms to match new SQL statements to existing, unused
>   execution plans in the cache require
>   that all object references be fully
>   qualified. For example, the first of
>   these SELECT statements is not matched
>   with an existing plan, and the second
>   is matched:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM Contact
>
> SELECT * FROM Person.Contact
> ```

And for NT connections you can't specify default schema so can't avoid this

And if you want [SCHEMABINDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) in views etc then you have to qualify schema.

etc

It's far more than "code clutter"

**Edit: after your comment elsewhere...**

You have run create table with no schema so you have an object `[domain\user].AgencyProfile`. Of course `dbo.AgencyProfile` does not exist

You need to run ['ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [domain\user].AgencyProfile TO dbo'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx) which replaces [sp_changeobjectowner](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177519.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the prefix/schema, but as Andy points out you don't have to use it if you don't have other schemas in the database.